# Как в eclipse добавить плагин через форму по аналогии с зависимостями в pom.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Как в *eclipse* добавить плагин через форму по аналогии с зависимостями в *pom.xml*?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы имеете в виду плагин к самому Eclipse, то он устанавливается через <kbd>Help</kbd> → <kbd>Install New Software</kbd>.

Если плагин к проекту — для этого используется Maven, который работает в эклипсе точно так же, как и в других IDE. (Добавляете зависимость в `pom.xml`).

Чтобы работать с Maven через Eclipse, вам нужно установить в нем плагин "m2e – Maven Integration for Eclipse"

Comment: немного уточню, обычно я в ручную прописывал теги  а сегодня случайно обнаружил форму . туда пишеш свои параметры зависимость автоматом появляется в pom.xml, у меня возникла мысль, может и для плагинов должна быть форма

Comment: @ИванСаенко: для каких плагинов-то? Которые к самому Eclipse?

Comment: например `<plugin><artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>    <version>2.4</version><configuration>   <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>     <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>    </configuration></plugin>`

Comment: Очевидно, товарищ имеет ввиду плагины самого мавена.

Comment: @IgorKudryashov: да, я понял. Пока не нашел ответа.

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой мыши на pom.xml файле или на проекте в "Project Explorer", выбрать меню Maven->Add Plugin